# Adding a general parameter to all ajax calls made with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using AJAX to load data from the server as needed. I'm currently working on updating the server software to the latest version. One of the things I noticed that has changed is that every request now requires me to pass along a token. This means I have to add a new parameter to every request. I'm hoping to achieve this by a general method, without having to modify every single AJAX call.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method as illustrated in the [following article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm).

Answer (score 10):

What you're looking for is a [Prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/), here's a sample from the page:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  // Modify options, control originalOptions, store jqXHR, etc
});
```

This requires JQuery 1.5.

Comment: If you're passing a string vs. object, you will need to use prefilter to append the parameter. We have this: beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {settings.data = settings.data+'&foo=bar'; return true; }

Comment: Thanks I found this more handy and more generic

Answer (score 0):

An example using [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) to extend posted data :

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' || options.type === 'POST') {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({},originalOptions.context.options.data,{ property:"val",property_two: "val" });
        options.context.options.data = modifiedData;
        options.data = $.param(modifiedData,true);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I took Raja Khoury's solution, but edited it a bit since context was null in my case.

This is what I came up with:

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' || options.type === 'POST') {
            var modifiedData = $.extend({}, originalOptions.data, { __RequestVerificationToken: getAntiForgeryToken() });
            options.data = $.param(modifiedData);
        }
    });
```