# Add a parameter to all ajax calls with method POST made with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Answer is simular to [Adding a general parameter to all ajax calls made with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270751/adding-a-general-parameter-to-all-ajax-calls-made-with-jquery), but I need to add additional param only for ajax calls with method post:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

May I achieve this without adding param into all ajax calls directly (editing inplace), i.e. via setup param via some sort of common config?

Comment: You should look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Comment: You could try having two data vars. one for post and one for get.

Comment: Further to @VigneswaranMarimuthu's comment, you can look at `originalOptions.type` to see if it's `"POST"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for comments.

I've also found this post usefull: [jQuery's ajaxSetup - I would like to add default data for GET requests only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996993/jquerys-ajaxsetup-i-would-like-to-add-default-data-for-get-requests-only)

Solution is (not fully tested yet):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions.type == 'POST') {
        originalOptions.data = $.extend(
            originalOptions.data,
            {
                some_dummy_data: 'lksflkdflksdlkf'
            }
        );
    }
});
```

**P.S. My final solution:**

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        options.data += '&some_dummy_data=lksflkdflksdlkf';
        if (options.data.charAt(0) == '&') {
            options.data = options.data.substr(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. `options.type` contains post in lowercase (just in case I've added
   `toLowerCase`)
2. `options.data` is string, not object, so I've rewrited query change via plain string manipulation
3. `originalOptions` didn't worked, but with `options` it workes.

Comment: I don't think you need - `originalOptions.data = $.extend(originalOptions.data, {some_dummy_data: 'lksflkdflksdlkf'});`. $.extend will merge into the target object which is `originalOptions.data`. Also, you don't need `$.extend`. You can simply add `originalOptions.data.<PROPERTY> = <VALUE>` unless you are adding more properties to original options

Comment: In my case `originalOptions` manipulations didn't help me achieve needed results. And `options.data` is string, not object. I've updated the answer. Thanks for help.